# App installs tracking

Tags: android, facebook

I'm creating my own Android app.

I need your help: I was thinking about promoting my app via a sort of "share" on various social networks. The problem is I need to track from where the user downloaded my app.

For example: the user receives from a friend via fb the link of my app on the Google Play store. So the user click on it and he is redirected to the app's page. Is there a way for knowing from where the user downloaded the app clicking on the link? I need to know it :)

Hope I explained well my problem :)

Ty all for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

It might be worthwhile if you have a look at the available metrics for the insights of your Page respectively your app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights#availmetrics

There are some "Special Values" which could be of interest as well: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights#specialvalues

Maybe it's also worthwhile to have a look here: https://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Ref If you see a `fb_source` URL parameter once people are arriving at your app. Official docs can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas/referral-tracking

Comment: Checking these useful links I started thinking if there was a wayto know WHO downloaded the app. Example: A friend clicks on the link on his fb's wall, he is redirected tothe google play store. I'd want to track that this guy download it from faceook link. Ty :D @Tobi

Comment: That's a separate question I think. If my answer was useful to you so far please accept it.